# Date pattern for WhatsApp chat text file that has 24 hour format, split() Error: too many values to unpack

Tags: python, pandas, date, nlp

I have a WhatsApp chat text file from iOs, where it has a 24hour format

> [07/04/2018, 14:11:22] Mike:

I want to create a Dataframe from the text. I've tried different date patterns e.g.

```
def dateTimeios(s):
    pattern = '^\[([0-9]+)(\/)([0-9]+)(\/)([0-9]+), ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9])?\] ' #(AM|PM|am|pm)?
    result = re.match(pattern, s)
    if result:
        return True
    return False
```

but they're not working. If I add + [**:([0-9]+)** ]on the seconds I get `split()` Error: too many values to unpack [image]

Comment: post the whole error/stacktrace please

Comment: I have added a screenshot to expound the source of the error.

Comment: on that line in your screenshot `date, time = dateTime.split(", ")` check what your input is, you're getting more than 2 values returned from `.split`

Comment: I have manage to create spaces between `pattern = '^\[([0-9]+)(\/)([0-9]+)(\/)([0-9]+), ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9])?\] '` and also on the split line I changed to this`splitline = line.split('] ')`. I'm not getting popping errors but the dataframe is not displaying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
x = re.search(r"^\[([0-9]+)(\/)([0-9]+)(\/)([0-9]+), ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)]", s)

print(x.group())
```

Your output:

```
>>> [07/04/2018, 14:11:22]
```

Have a look at this [example](https://regex101.com/r/Rp0atV/1).

Comment: I have tried to implement. I have added a screenshot to expound the source of the error.

Comment: I have manage to create spaces between `pattern = '^\[([0-9]+)(\/)([0-9]+)(\/)([0-9]+), ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9])?\] '` and also on the split line I changed to this`splitline = line.split('] ')`. I'm not getting popping errors but the dataframe is not displaying.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: A data frame that has the date, time, contact and message as columns and its data

Comment: You can use regex to extract every data you desire from the string, without using `.split()`, and then locate them to columns

Comment: Ok , hear me on this...then work it out without `split()`....

`pattern = '^\[([0-9]+)(\/)([0-9]+)(\/)([0-9]+), ([0-9]+):([0-9]+):([0-9]+)?\ ]'
result = re.match(pattern, s)`
I'm using re.match() to match each input pattern on the date time then I append it to the other columns. I can't tell whether the empty/null return is resulted by the splitline or the pattern using regex.

Comment: That’s because your regex has no match. Use the one I typed in my answer and see the example provided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238924/discussion-between-ruggero-and-mickeywise).